# quickly adding email address for .NetCore MailKit smtp utility

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, mailkit

I found a little email utility for MailKit .NetCore.

I got it to work, but I can't figure out how to add more than one email recipient.

I can one like this:

```
EmailAddress toAddress = new EmailAddress()
{
    Name = "Ken Watanabe",
    Address = "kw100@xxxx.com"
};

var newMessage = new EmailMessage()
```

And then it is added to a new EmailMessage like this:

```
newMessage.ToAddresses.Add(toAddress);
```

The EmailMessage class looks like this:

```
public class EmailMessage
{
    public EmailMessage()
    {
        ToAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        FromAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
    }

    public List<EmailAddress> ToAddresses { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> FromAddresses { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then it is passed onto another method to be sent:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.To.AddRange(emailMessage.ToAddresses.Select(x => new MailboxAddress(x.Name, x.Address)));
```

I guess I can create new recipients like this:

```
EmailAddress toAddress1 = new EmailAddress()
{
    Name = "Ken Watanabe",
    Address = "kw100@xxxx.com"
};

    EmailAddress toAddress2 = new EmailAddress()
{
    Name = "Ryosuke Yamada",
    Address = "ry1010104@yyyy.com"
};

newMessage.ToAddresses.Add(toAddress1);
newMessage.ToAddresses.Add(toAddress2);
```

But I was wondering if there would be an easier way that didn't require as much code.

Is there a way to just add the info instead of having to create a separate EmailAddress object for each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the `EmailAddress` class then the easiest change would be to make a class constructor with parameters for name and email e.g.

```cs
public class EmailAddress
{
    public EmailAddress() { }

    public EmailAddress(name, address) 
    { 
        Name = name;
        Address = address;  
    }
    // ...
```

Then you can create the new email address and add it directly to the list of addresses. e.g.

```cs
newMessage.ToAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress("Ken Watanabe", "kw100@xxxx.com"));
newMessage.ToAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress("Ryosuke Yamada", "ry1010104@yyyy.com"));
```